# Python: How to replace each instance of an object with an ordered number?

Tags: python, loops

The title may be a little cryptic so I'll elaborate on it here.

I've got a list of objects that are defined like so:

```
pname {
'amondo': 'amondo',
'android13': 'android13',
'android13s': 'android13s',
'android14': 'android14',
```

351 objects in total.

What I'm trying to do is replace the text in *left-side quote* with numbers starting from 1. So the end result would be something like:

```
'1': 'amondo',
'2': 'android13',
'3': 'android13s',
'4': 'android14',
```

all the way up until the last object.

I've created a python script with the following code:

```
import re

f = open('name.js', 'r')

inp = []
outp = []


for i in f:
    inp.append(i)

for i in inp:
    x = 1
    while x < 352:
        r = re.sub('.*\:', "'" + str(x) + "':", i)
        x+=1

    outp.append(r)


o = open('done.js', 'w')

for i in outp:
    o.write(i)

f.close()
o.close()
```

But the output is:

```
'351': 'amondo',
'351': 'android13',
'351': 'android13s',
'351': 'android14',
```

---

I understand what I'm doing wrong and why the output is what it is but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

There's probably a function out there that could help me that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Tip: your `while` loop is inside the `for` loop,  so...think what will happen.

Comment: @KevinGuan Yeah, like it says in the OP, I already knew what I was doing wrong (loop in a loop) but I couldn't think of an alternative. Just put it up there anyways to show what I've been working with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully at your while loop, nothing is stopping it until x=352 and then you append r, this is not what you want... An easy way to count line is to use enumerate:

```
for x,i in enumerate(f):
    r = re.sub('.*\:', "'" + str(x) + "':", i)
    outp.append(r)
```

Comment: Both answers worked great but this one was the most simple and relevant to my original code. Thanks!!

Comment: PS: did you notice that you can enumerate f directly? No need to feed it into inp first...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('name.js') as infile, open('done.js', 'w') as outfile:
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        if ":" not in line:
            outfile.write(line)
            continue
        count += 1
        _, val = line.strip().split(":")
        outfile.write("'{}' : {}\n".format(count, val))
```